# how to calculate Average time, standard deviation, Throughput to measure Performance

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

[Summary Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJyxG.png)
I have set  a thread of 1500 with a ramp up period of 100, Could any one please tell me how should i verify the report generated by Jmeter.
Calculation of Average, Standard deviation and throughput.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the formulas - they're all available in the [Calculator](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java) class.

- **Average** response time: is basically a sum of all Sample Results elapsed time divided by their number, in other words [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean)
- **Standard Deviation**: is normal [statistical measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of result set values distribution
- **Throughput**: is [number of requests divided by total test duration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

It is not clear what you mean by "verify", if you want to fail certain samplers if their response time exceeds certain threshold values you can use [Duration Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) or define reasonable timeouts using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)

[image]

---

If you want to process calculated values like mark test as failed if average response time is greater than X milliseconds or throughput is lower than Y requests for the specified duration or standard deviation for full response time is greater than Z milliseconds unfortunately as of [JMeter 5.1.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-1-released-td5728320.html) it is not possible out of the box, however you can consider using [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation/) tool as a wrapper for your JMeter test, Taurus is capable of ["understanding" JMeter tests](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File) and you can add [custom pass/fail criteria](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) including but not limited to the metrics you listed.